# 60s SF show: "Citizen of Alta on the Planet Protos"

Tags: story-identification, aliens, tv

Does anyone recall a SF programme (possibly part of a series) that I saw as a kid in the 1960s?

The central character discovers a plot by aliens to take over the world. After various attempts to alert others to their presence (possibly landing himself in a mental hospital, but I can't swear to that) he is captured and an alien sneers that his people are "only 20th century? We're in the 1100th century now." The man begins to scream "I am [name] citizen of Alta on the planet Protos."

These events are happening over 100,000 years in the future, and the "aliens" are from Earth.

Comment: Was it a children's show, or a "grown-up" show you saw as a kid? And what country were you living in when you saw it?

Comment: Since he spells program programme I guess that he comes from a country where British English is used instead of American English

Comment: In the UK. I would have been in my teens, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't a kids' programme.

Comment: Was it in color or black & white? You're from the UK? but do you think the show was UK made?

Comment: I saw it in black and white. My parents didn't get a colour set until some years later. I don't str any American accents, though it was a heck of  a long time ago so that isn't conclusive.

Answer (score 3):

Thank for all your help. I've found it.

It was Terry Nation's *Botany Bay*, in Boris Karloff's sf series *Out of this world.* Sadly it apparently hasn't survived, but hopefully some old reel will turn up one day in a loft or garage.

See the following at http://www.britishtelevisiondrama.org.uk/?p=213

> Nation also wrote the first of only two original scripts presented by the 
>   series. Botany Bay was a horrific tale with some effective plot twists and direction. The Times’s ‘Special Correspondent’ noted that the play was “Particularly disturbing”, reporting how Guy Verney’s direction derived “the maximum effect from keeping us – literally as well as metaphorically – very much in the dark.” Set in a sinister psychiatric institute, the story concerned aliens transferring their minds into those of the inmates.
>
> The final twist reveals that the story is not in fact set on earth after all. The Special Correspondent found it as gloomy as previous episodes, “doubly so, in fact, since not only did we see intelligences – apparently evil intelligences – from another planet triumphing over ordinary people like you and me, but worse, by an ingenious twist at the end we were made to realise that we ourselves, the inhabitants of earth, were the sinister intruders on some simpler future world: that not only were the wrong ‘uns winning, but they were us after some further centuries of decadence.” As an original and intriguing teleplay in a series largely comprised of adaptations it is particularly sad that no recording of this instalment survives.